# Rails 3.2: multiple nested data from one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create form and action for multiple nested attributes if:

LineItem:

```
has_many :item_options, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :product_options, :through => :item_options
```

ProductOption:

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :option
has_many :item_options
has_many :line_items, :through => :item_options
```

ItemOption:

```
attr_accessible :line_item_id, :product_option_id  
belongs_to :line_item, :foreign_key => "line_item_id"
belongs_to :product_option,:foreign_key => "product_option_id"
```

When I'm creating new LineItem, I need to create new ItemOption(s). This is my form:

```
        <%= form_for(LineItem.new) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %>
        <%= f.fields_for :item_options do |io| %>
            <% @product.options.uniq.each do |o| %>
              <%= o.name %>: 
              <%= io.collection_select :product_option_id, o.product_options.where(:product_id => @product.id), :id, :value %>
            <% end %>
        <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
```

When I'm clicking on Add To Cart, I've get:

ItemOption(#70296453751440) expected, got Array(#70296430421140)

When Adding accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_options to LineItem, my selects not diplayed :(

With

```
<%= select_tag "product_option_id", options_from_collection_for_select(o.product_options.where(:product_id => @product.id), :id, :value) %>
#item_options not created:
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/WM5/MqPn1yCxjKWoJQmjfko2pR4RiYV0S2KeTTpA3w=", "line_item"=>{"product_id"=>"1"}, "product_option_id"=>"5", "commit"=>"add"}
```

And last one, I've create action like this:

```
@line_item = LineItem.new(params[:line_item])
@line_item.item_options.build 
....
```

Where am I wrong? :( I'm totally confused.
ps. similar question [Rails 3.2 has_many through form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199572/rails-3-2-has-many-through-form-submission)
This is form:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks this line:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/WM5/MqPn1yCxjKWoJQmjfko2pR4RiYV0S2KeTTpA3w=", "line_item"=>{"product_id"=>"1"}, "product_option_id"=>"5", "commit"=>"add"}
```

The parameter `product_option_id` is outside `line_item` hash, and will be inside. Maybe you need write the select like this:

```
<%= select_tag "line_item[product_option_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(o.product_options.where(:product_id => @product.id), :id, :value) %>
```

I'm not sure, but maybe is this. Maybe I need more information, like the exact line where is failing.

---

Extra, the `:foreign_key => "line_item_id"` and `:foreign_key => "product_option_id"` are not necesary, because, the `belongs_to` model name is the same and will use these foreign_key. From [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is
>   guessed to be the name of the association with an “**_id**” suffix. So
>   a class that defines a `**belongs_to :person**` association will use
>   “**person_id**” as the default **:foreign_key**. Similarly, **belongs_to
>   :favorite_person, :class_name => "Person"** will use a foreign key of
>   “**favorite_person_id**”.

---

**Edit**

Sorry, the `unknown attribute: product_option_id` is because the attribute name is **product_option**_ids, and is an array, not a unique value. For a `has_many` relationship, the *column* name is **collection_singular**_ids, and the select should be:

```
<%= select_tag "line_item[product_option_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(o.product_options.where(:product_id => @product.id), :id, :value) %>
```

This should work, I think :)...

Comment: Tnx, but `unknown attribute: product_option_id` ... In params: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ik5ad6KsTOD+b4e9ioenFqfXY1nojXdEGAeNAXlCN8E=",
 "line_item"=>{"product_id"=>"1",
 "product_option_id"=>"5"},
 "commit"=>"Добавить в корзину"}`

Comment: Maybe it's something like: `<%= select_tag "item_option[product_option_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(o.product_options.where(:product_id => @product.id), :id, :value) %>` But it's only one item_option, even have several in form :( Params: `"line_item"=>{"product_id"=>"1"}, "item_option"=>{"product_option_id"=>"4"}, `

Comment: This variant is better: `<%= select_tag "item_option[][product_option_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(o.product_options.where(:product_id => @product.id), :id, :value) %>`, than in params: `"line_item"=>{"product_id"=>"1"}, "item_option"=>[{"product_option_id"=>"1"}, {"product_option_id"=>"4"}]`. But still not saving (

Comment: You have the column in your `attr_accessible`?, like `attr_accessible :product_option_ids` or `attr_accesible :product_option_id`. **Edit**, late :P